# GCP: Creating a snapshot of a VM including runtime processes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, snapshot

From what I could find, Google Cloud will only allow me to create a snapshot of a machine disk.

Is it possible in some way to also capture its runtime? i.e RAM and process states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, snapshots are limited to the persistent disk and not runtime processes and RAM. I would also like to mention that it is not possible to have a snapshot of RAM as this is volatile memory.

Comment: Also even if you snapshot the RAM, whenever you restore that using the snapshot it would not be a valid, since volatile memory is valid only at that point of time. You cannot record volatile memory and use it further for repair. You could try flushing the data from the ram to hit that to disk and that would make the snapshot application aware and hence that would be much more helpful when you want to restore from the snapshots taken